# Why is row number added as a column in csv file saved by pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two lists of strings named `input_rems_text` and `input_text`.I save them as a csv file.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['A']=input_rems_text
df['B']=input_text    
df.to_csv('MyLists.csv', sep="\t")
```

The output of `df.shape` is [10000,2]

The problem is when I read the csv file with the this code:

```
 with open('MyLists.csv', 'r') as file:
  for line_num, row in enumerate(csv.reader(file, delimiter='\t')):
     print(len(row))
```

I get 3 as the row length. and when I print the `row` itself the row number is also present as a separate column in beginning of the row. What is my mistake? how can I dump csv file for two lists with just 2 columns?

Comment: Use `df.to_csv('MyLists.csv', sep="\t", index=False)` while saving the csv.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set `index` parameter to `False` on `to_csv` function.

```py
df.to_csv('MyLists.csv', sep="\t", index=False)
```

[Documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)

Answer (score 1):

"Row numbers in CSV file" is called "row index". To suppress row index when you save CSV with [`df.to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html), specify `index=False`.

Btw pandas has its own builtin `pd.read_csv` command for reading, so use it, no need to use base Python `csv.reader` as you're doing:

```
df2 = pd.read_csv('MyLists.csv', sep='\t')
```